# Linking with LAPACK library under OS 10.14.3 and Xcode 9.0

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, lapack

I'm trying to compile a simple Fortran code (with [gfortran 8.2.2](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases)) in which I access some LAPACK routines on OS 10.14.3. Unfortunately, I can no longer link with the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) (which used to work fine for a long time). For example,

```
gfortran -framework Accelerate abc.o def.o -o mycode
```

now leads to

```
ld: framework not found Accelerate
```

I've installed Xcode 9.0 and the developer tools.

It's been a while since I've compiled that code and I've updated the OS,  Xcode, and gfortran since then so I cannot trace the problems to a single change. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed the [Command Line Tools for Xcode 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)? Alternatively, does `gfortran` accept a `-isysroot` option? If so, try `-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk`. If not, try setting the environment variable `SDKROOT` to the same path.

Comment: I thought I had installed the command-line tools, but I'm not sure. The only version of them for Xcode 9.0 I could find was for macOS 10.13, however, whereas I'm at 10.14, so I had to install Xcode 10, but this leads to the error message "Required content for platform tvOS Simulator is missing. Please reinstall Xcode." The only helpful webpage is on an Apple Developer Forum, which I should be able to access, but it forced me to sign up again. I'm waiting for the confirmation...

Comment: I simply reinstalled Xcode 10 and this time it worked. After installing the command-line tools, the code now compiles. Thanks for the pointer about the command-line tools. Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need(ed) to install the Command Line Tools.